# How to use Safari Web Inspector for "Designed for iPad" apps running on Apple Silicon (M1) macOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, wkwebview, safari-web-inspector

I have an iPad app that uses a WKWebView. When I run it from Xcode in the iOS Simulator or on an iOS device, I can see the webviews show up in the Develop menu in Safari.
However, when I run that same app with the "My Mac (Designed for iPad)" run destination, I see "No Inspectable Applications" under "Johannes' MacBook Pro" in the Safari Develop menu.

According to session 420 from WWDC 2016 (https://archive.org/details/wwdc2016videos/420_hd_optimizing_web_content_in_your_app.mp4), it's necessary to add "com.apple.webinspector.allow" to the entitlement when trying to inspect a webview in a macOS app. I did that, but when I try to run the app on my Mac from Xcode, the build fails saying "Provisioning profile "Springenwerk Development" doesn't include the com.apple.webinspector.allow entitlement." So it seems like the `com.apple.webinspector.allow` entitlement only works for "pure" macOS apps, not for iPad apps that can also run on M1 Macs.

So my question is: How can I use the Safari Web Inspector to inspect web views in a "Designed for iPad" app running on my M1 Mac when running it from Xcode?